# Can I connect a second keyless light fixture and control both from one pull-chain?

Tags: lighting

[image: h]I have an existing light with power from a junction box operated by a pull chain. Can I add a new light and have it operated by the existing pull chain. Would like to have both lights turn on at the same time.

Comment: Maybe.  Can you show us a picture of the back side of the fixture?  You can [edit] your post to add a pic.

Comment: Both black and white wires are added to the appropriate terminals.

Comment: I'm sure. I'm looking for *other stuff*.

Answer (score 4):

### Possible, with a change of fixture

I mean, we are dealing with a 2 dollar lightbulb holder here.

The problem is, we will need to feed the downline light with a) neutral, and b) *switched-hot*: the electrical point *between* the switch and the bulb.

On this particular fixture, the switch and socket base are integral, and they don't make that point accessible. At all.

So you'd need to find a model of fixture where they do expose it at a tappable screw.

At that point, neutral would stay where it is, and hot for the downline cable would be placed on the screw.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, get one of those socket to outlet extenders and an extension cord, and a plug to socket adapter. You can figure out the rest.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, a field-built swag :) with adequate physical support, this works under Code